# How to automatically open a regular window?

Tags: windows, home-automation

In the winter I always face an issue where I occasionally need to ventilate the room whenever the air feels "stiff". I cannot leave the window open since the air is too cold and doing it manually is a bit annoying.

Is there a system I can install on my window to automatically open it remotely? My windows are standard European plastic ones and look approximate like this:

[image]

Comment: Carbon monoxide levels can of course be high enough to cause illness or even death, but I have never heard of carbon dioxide levels being a problem except in submarines and spacecraft. Does this actually occur in ordinary terrestrial structures?

Comment: @JimStewart the dioxide is formed when breathing and that's what causes the "stiffness" you feel in the air when the windows are shut for too long. It won't cause illness, but it's unpleasant.

Comment: Are there any CO2 detectors available commercially for use in a home?

Comment: @JimStewart certainly. I've heard good references about [this model](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Digital-3-in1-Round-Desktop-Indoor-Air-Quality-Datalogger-Temperature-Relative-Humidity-RH-0-9999ppm-range/891184272.html). There are also plenty of standalone sensors one can connect to a microcomputer.

Comment: It would seem to me that one ought to do some data logging for months or a year to determine if one had a high CO2 problem before investing in a system to automatically vent. It seems more people in the US are getting air exchange systems to bring in fresh air. These are under the control of the HVAC system. I have never heard of one in which a motor and levers or gears were used to open or close an ordinary window. If it were I, I would just operate the window manually when I felt the need.

Comment: @JimStewart it's a no-brainer actually. The global CO2 level is around 400 ppm - both in New York City and in the middle of a forest. The room starts feeling "stiff" at 800ppm. If there's an automatic ventilation system I can easily retrofit into my window, that would be fine as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58253/discussion-between-jim-stewart-and-jonathanreez).

Comment: I'm not sure what the outcome in chat was. This question would be easier to answer if it was changed to ONLY be about opening windows or ONLY about dealing with high CO2+stuffy rooms.

Comment: @Freiheit post updated

Comment: @JonathanReez Take a look at this page: https://www.hometron.com/window-opener-systems

Answer (score 2):

Not really. There are plenty of ventilation systems in use, but it would be cumbersome and expensive to involve windows.

Exhaust fans do the job by sending stale air out. This creates a very slight low pressure condition inside the home, so that even if there's no "makeup air" or air exchange system installed, air will be drawn in through the many small leaks any home has.

I strongly suggest that you install a digital/smart timer on your bath fan or furnace so that you can run them on a schedule or on demand, instead of seeking a motorized apparatus that's likely to be unsightly and noisy.